# Redux reducer not updating state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following code, and I am trying to update the state but it is not working.

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import _un  from 'underscore';
import { List, Map } from 'immutable'; 

const defaultState = Map({
  isFetching:true,
  deparments: List(),
  products:List(),
  breadcrumb:List()
})
```

I am using set but when I console before return it just prints the original object. What am I doing wrong?

```
switch(action.type) {
     case 'GET_GALLERY_DATA':

      //console.log("-- api success handler--");
      //console.log(action);

       var depts = getGalleryParsedData(action.res.data);
       var products = getProducts(action.res.data);
       var breadcrumb = getBreadcrumbs(action.res.data);

      state.set('isFetching', true);
      state.set('deparments', List(depts))
      state.set('products', List(products))
      //state.set('breadcrumb', List(breadcrumb))

     console.log("---state----");
     console.log(state);
      return state;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Immutable.js` does not *mutate* your state, it returns a mutated copy of the original object.

```js
state = state.set('isFetching', true);
state = state.set('deparments', List(depts));
state = state.set('products', List(products));
```

or

```js
state = state
  .set('isFetching', true)
  .set('deparments', List(depts))
  .set('products', List(products));
```

Comment: are u aware of this code https://github.com/bananaoomarang/isomorphic-redux

Comment: its isomorphic app, so i changed reducer to have complex object like this, do i need to change anything else to make it work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121684/discussion-between-kobe-and-martriay).